# Expected Value of a Max vs Max of an Expected value

Tags: probability, expectation

Let  c = $max_{j\in[m]}$ E[$C_j$], where $C_j$ = $\frac{1}{s_j} \sum_1^n w_i p_i^j$.

$C$ = E[$max_{j\in [m]} C_j$]

Two questions, first what is C. It sure looks like to me that we are just taking the expected value of of a constant. 2nd question: c $\leq C$. Why is this so? It's supposed to be obvious, but it is not to me. Is it always the case that the expected value of a max is >= the max of a expected value?

I'm trying to follow the argument here: http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~czumaj/PUBLICATIONS/DRAFTS/SODA-2002-Full.pdf on starting with equation (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easiest to see if you imagine a zero-mean process with a large variance. No matter how big the variance gets, *the mean will still hang out around zero*. Taking the max of the expected value is similar to asking how far the ***sample average*** strayed from the mean.

On the other hand, as the variance of our zero-mean process increases, the max values will also tend to increase.  Taking the expected value of the max is similar to asking how far the **farthest samples** strayed from the mean on average.

This is a big simplification, but hopefully it gives some extra intuition.  Also, I am an engineer, not a mathematician, so I apologize if my terminology is somewhat engineering-specific.